# duplicating github's topbar behavior with a bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Github's bar at the top is what I'm attempting to duplicate using Bootstraps navbar class (https://github.com/).

Notice how the bar extends to fill the entire browser window, while the core elements stay in place in their fixed column? That's what I'm attempting to figure out.

I have the following code.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <img src="/img/logo_sml.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My thinking was, if I close the main `container`, I could the place the `navbar` and have it fill the entire length of the browser. This worked as planned, but when I add things to the `navbar` they appear all the way on the left side of the page (as expected).

So! I then thought I could start a new `container` into which I would put the menu items, thus having then appear in the central column where they should.

Wrapping up a menu element:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <img src="/img/logo_sml.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Refreshed the page, and... that didn't work. Is there a way to extend the "tails" of a Bootstrap `navbar` while keeping the content in the main `container`?

Here's the result adding in the `contatiner` class. The elements sit all the way on the left hand of the browser.

[image]

Comment: When you say "that didn't work" toward the end of your question, what happened? Placing a container div inside the `.navbar .navbar-inner` element should do the trick. You can see an example here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

Comment: @fletch Hmm.. I just copied and pasted the code. It seem the *only* way to works is if it's a `fixed-top` bar.. If I delete that line, everything scoots over to the left again. That's kind of lame..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the css has a property:

```
.navbar .container {
   width: auto;
}
```

If you put a css property that has

```
.navbar .container {
   width: 940px;
}
```

It should work as you expected.

You can see the used code in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/raT7R/) and [the final result in full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/MRUuG/embedded/result/).

Comment: if you go to use bootstrap-responsive, make sure you define a matching `width` in the various media queries.